# Relating generically created Django objects with users

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Python & Django. I want to allow users to create new objects, and for each object to be related to the currently logged in user. So, I thought I'd use the generic create_object method - only I can't work out how best to do this so it's simple and secure.

Here's my model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner',
        editable=False)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,
        help_text='A title for this entry')

    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

This is a really simple model - users can enter a book title and author, and the 'user' field is set as non-editable. When the object is created I want the user field to have the value of the currently logged in user.

Can I do this with the generic create_object method? What's the best approach here? I don't want to use a hidden field in the form since it's obviously not safe.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not possible with generic view (I could think of some way to accomplish that, but that would be much more complicated than it's worth - using signals, globals and middleware). You should write your own view that will handle Book object creation using ModelForm. Read about it [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view) and [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#a-full-example) (Django docs).

Also, I think you misunderstood what `related_name` parameter does - now, given some User instance you'll have to write:

```
books = user.owner.all()
```

to get list of this user's books. It would be better to either leave `related_name` unchanged (the default is `relatedmodelname_set`, in this case: `user.book_set.all()`) or change it to something more meaningful, like `"books"`, which will let you write:

```
books = user.books.all()
```

and get what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if there was an easy way to do this, but I'll just make a new view. Thanks for clarifying the related_name parameter.